# Load numpy array in google-cloud-ml job

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

In the model I want to launch, I have some variables which have to be initialized with specific values.

I currently store these variables into numpy arrays but I don't know how to adapt my code to make it work on a google-cloud-ml job.

Currently I initialize my variable like this:

```
my_variable = variables.model_variable('my_variable', shape=None, dtype=tf.float32, initializer=np.load('datasets/real/my_variable.npy'))
```

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First, you'll need to copy/store the data on GCS (using, e.g., `gsutil`) and ensure your training script has access to that bucket. The easiest way to do so is to copy the array to the same bucket as your data, since you'll likely already have configured that bucket for read access. If the bucket is in the same project as your training job and you followed [these](https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/how-tos/getting-set-up) instructions (particularly, `gcloud beta ml init-project`), you should be set. If the data will be in another bucket, see [these](https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/how-tos/using-external-buckets) instructions.

Then you'll need to use a library capable of loading data from GCS. Tensorflow includes a module that can do this, although you're free to use any client library that can read from GCS. Here's an example of using TensorFlow's `file_io` module:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python.lib.io import file_io

# Create a variable initialized to the value of a serialized numpy array
f = StringIO(file_io.read_file_to_string('gs://my-bucket/123.npy'))
my_variable = tf.Variable(initial_value=np.load(f), name='my_variable')
```

Note that we have to read the file into a string and use `StringIO`, since `file_io.FileIO` does not fully implement the seek function required by `numpy.load`.

Bonus: in case it's useful, you can directly store a numpy array to GCS using the `file_io` module, e.g.:

```
np.save(file_io.FileIO('gs://my-bucket/123', 'w'), np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]))
```

For Python 3, use `from io import StringIO` instead of `from StringIO import StringIO`.

Answer (score 5):

I tried the accepted answer but ran into some problems.  Eventually this worked for me (Python 3):

```
from io import BytesIO
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python.lib.io import file_io
```

To save:

```
array = np.ones((100, ))
dest = 'gs://[BUCKET-NAME]/' # Destination to save in GCS
np.save(file_io.FileIO(dest, 'w'), array)
```

To load:

```
f = BytesIO(file_io.read_file_to_string(src, binary_mode=True))
arr = np.load(f)
```