# How to load numpy npz files in google-cloud-ml jobs or from Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I have a google-cloud-ml job that requires loading numpy .npz files from gs bucket. I followed [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41633748/load-numpy-array-in-google-cloud-ml-job) on how to load .npy files from gs, but it didn't work for me since .npz files are compressed.

Here's my code:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python.lib.io import file_io

f = StringIO(file_io.read_file_to_string('gs://my-bucket/data.npz'))
data = np.load(f)
```

And here's the error message:

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa2 in position 10: invalid start byte`

Apparently, encoding the data to `str` is not correct, but I'm not sure how to address this.

Can some one help? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out I need to set the binary flag to `True` in `file_io.read_file_to_string()`.

Here's the working code:

```
from io import BytesIO
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python.lib.io import file_io

f = BytesIO(file_io.read_file_to_string('gs://my-bucket/data.npz', binary_mode=True))
data = np.load(f)
```

And this works for both compressed and uncompressed .npz files.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `io.BytesIO` instead, which has the added bonus of being forwards-compatible with Python 3:

```
import io
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python.lib.io import file_io

f = io.BytesIO(file_io.read_file_to_string('gs://my-bucket/data.npz'),
               binary_mode=True)
data = np.load(f)
```

Comment: Tried it, but still didn't work -- got the same error message. Thanks though!

Comment: setting `binary_mode=True` in `read_file_to_string` then your code works. Thanks.

Comment: I just edited the code, thanks. Strange though, it ran fine on the test I did, but this looks better anyways.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is (note the difference between earlier TF versions and later ones):

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python.lib.io import file_io
from tensorflow import __version__ as tf_version

if tf_version >= '1.1.0':
    mode = 'rb'
else: # for TF version 1.0
    mode = 'r'

f_stream = file_io.FileIO('mydata.npz', mode)
d = np.load( BytesIO(f_stream.read()) )
```

Similarly, for pickle files:

```
import pickle
d = pickle.load(file_io.FileIO('mydata.pickle', mode))
```