# Best way to store images for Google Cloud Machine Learning project?

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, keras, google-cloud-ml-engine

I am running a Machine Learning project using Google Cloud Platform with Tensorflow and Keras. I have about 30,000 PNG images in my dataset. When I run it locally, Keras has great utilities to load images but Google Cloud Services needs to use certain librairies such as `tensorflow.file_io` (see: [Load numpy array in google-cloud-ml job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41633748/load-numpy-array-in-google-cloud-ml-job)) in order to read in files from a GC bucket.

What is the best way to load the images from a Google Cloud Storage bucket? Right now I am saving them as bytes and reading them in from one file, but it would be great to be able to load the images directly from the GC bucket.

Thanks,